# Snooze on application destroy/close from android applications list

Tags: android, alarmmanager, activity-lifecycle

I have an alarm clock application. When alarm triggers, it shows an activity and plays the ring. However since it is playing inside an activity, user can close activity from applications list and it will exit the activity.

In this situation I want to snooze the alarm and using some samples I tried this:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.v("MY_TAG","Snooze alarm");
    AlarmUtils.setAlarm(...); // this will set snooze alarm
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

However the problem is onDetroy never called when application is closed from applications list.
I still checked the Android Monitor and it does not shows my log.

I want to know how can I apply this snooze method or how can I fix this?

Comment: Put that code inside onPause() instead of onDestroy()

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I tried that already, however it does not trigger like what happens for onDestory

Answer (score 1):

Ah I understand now.

Assuming the snooze time is 10 minutes, schedule the next snooze in 10 minutes as soon as the alarm starts sounding.

If the person does turn off the alarm instead of snoozing it, then turn off the sound and also delete the next snooze alarm in 10 minutes.

Each time a minute passes while the alarm is sounding, reset the scheduled alarm for the next 10 minutes (otherwise it will sound again in 9 minutes which is not what you want)

I know this logic sounds convoluted, but it should do what you want.

Comment: I used this as a workaround and its working. But it seems there are some tricks with this onDestroy which I have missed...

Comment: The problem is that onDestroy() is never guaranteed to be called. This is an Android specific limitation. It's how the platform was designed. Users want task killers, but they don't know what they're asking. A real task killer on a phone would only slow down the OS because clearing too much memory all at once could end up blocking the main thread and making the phone unresponsive.